# JavaScript code on working on SharePoint Online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, column, content-query-web-part

Hope you're well;

I am adding JavaScript code into content web part. However it is not working. I'm i mising something out.

[image]

[image]

Comment: need more info. what is it what you want to achieve? does your js gives error in console of browser (F12)?

Comment: error your code: <\/script> change to </script>

Comment: I want the writing of text to appear as drop down when you click on little triangle icon. it does work in SP2010 however it don't work in SP Online

Answer (score 0):

I prefer add your code into html file and give reference to content editor webpart. In this way, HTML will not get messed up while you are editing the page for second time, also your code will be stored securely in one file. In accident if the page got deleted or content editor got deleted then all your changes will go away. So put your script, css, html in `.html` file and give the link and see whether it is working or not.

Comment: Hello I followed what you done. nothing happens